# Does the Psi Warrior Telekinetic movement let you move an item you're standing on?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, psionics, archetype

as title, the telekinetic movement option says "One loose object that is Large or smaller or one willing creature other than yourself", does that mean that if say, i placed my shield on the ground, stood on it and used telekinetic movement i could indirectly move 30 feet in any direction by moving the shield? i'm asking because the definition of "Loose Object" is kinda murky. i interpreted it as "an object that is not bound or being held".

TL:DR can i use telekinetic movement to prop fly a la half life 2?

Comment: Yet you don't consider a shield being secured in place by your own mass bound or being held?

Comment: fair point but you'd still be able to move it from under someone's feet pretty easily

also i'm pretty sure you don't hold things with your feet

Comment: No :) and I get what you're aiming at. In the real world the whole "equal and opposite reaction" thing would prevent this but in DnD, who knows??

Comment: yeah!! i was mostly convinced by the fact that it can move up to a large item and/or a willing creature, so a small item with a creature standing on it shouldnt be difficult. btw, by "bound item" i ment like a door, witch, being bound to a wall, is by definition not loose. hope that clears my point (^^)

Answer (score 3):

### You do not move.

From a strictly RAW perspective: this (use of the) ability targets and moves an object, not "an object and anything the object is supporting". Regardless of whether your shield counts as 'loose' or not, this plan would not work- at best your shield would be sent skittering across the battlefield and you would remain unmoved.

From a RAI perspective, the wording of the ability says

> You can move an object or a creature with your mind. As an action, you target one loose object that is Large or smaller or one willing creature, **other than yourself**.

The ability specifically calls out that you cannot move yourself with this ability, so the rules-as-intended is pretty clear- you are not supposed to be able to pseudo-fly or drag yourself about with this ability.

Answer (score -2):

### [Loose](https://www.google.com/search?q=loose%20definition&oq=loose%20definition&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i10j0l2j0i10l2j0j69i60.3663j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) means "not firmly or tightly fixed in place; detached or able to be detached"

Something you are standing on is not loose.

Comment: personally i doubt someone standing on something is "firmly or tightly fixing it in place", i wouldn't call a carpet "fixed in place" because i'm standing on it, someone could easily sweep it from under my feet, but i can see how that'd figure from a rule pov. thank you!

Comment: @Mytha that rug - is it loose if only I stand on it but not loose if it has 3 sofas and a coffee table as well?

Comment: @Mytha Unlike a shield a carpet is a very long object that is very flexible. Try getting a carpet that is a small square. You will find it quite firmly fixed in place when it is stood on. Size is important for determining if something is fixed in place. A shield is designed to be solid and easy to raise in defence. As such it would be firmly fixed in place when stood on.

Comment: i see the point. maybe i should get a long rug as @TheGrandJ implied